# what's the benefit of using 'let' in for loop instead of 'var'

Tags: javascript

When I read code, some people use `var` but other people use `let`. I read that the `let` is the block scope, but if I use the `var` it's still block scope as you cannot use it outside of the `for loop`. 
What is the benefit of using `let` instead of `var` in the `for loop` as the below.

```
 for (let i = 0; i < action.payload.customers.length; i++)
```

Comment: This question has already been answered. Just try to dig in more using this link.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var

Comment: "*if I use the `var` it's still block scope as you cannot use it outside of the for loop*" - well, wrong. Just try a loop with `var` and do `console.log(i)` afterwards.